# CSS default width prior to selector

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to set a default width for a group of divs, but then change each width regardless of order in just CSS? Example JSFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/RfHSA/.

I'm attempting to have each div set to `width:20%`, but then upon the mouse hovering one of the inner divs, the specific div hovered over should be set to `width:72%` and the others set to `width:7%` (including ones that occur prior to it in the HTML structure). Is this possible with just CSS, or is Javascipt/jQuery required?

Edit: Example of what I'm trying to achieve is here: http://www.kriesi.at/themes/newscast/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to recommend an easy solution to your need: http://jsfiddle.net/linmic/qcnmu/1/

We simply apply display: table to the "listwrapper" and display: table-cell to the "outerbox", then everything works perfectly.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You were 99% there: http://jsfiddle.net/RfHSA/2/

```
.featuredwrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:350px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding-top:12px;
    position:relative;
}

.listwrapper {
    width:95%;
    max-width:1100px;
    height:325px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}

.listwrapper:hover .outerbox {
    width:7%;
}
.outerbox {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
    margin-left:-4px;
    box-shadow:-5px 0px 5px rgba(51,51,51,0.85);
    -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-out;    
}

.listwrapper:hover .outerbox:hover {
    width:72%;
}

.outerbox:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
}

.hoveractive {
    position:absolute;
    width:95%;
    height:325px;
    z-index:1000;
    padding-top:12px;
}
```

I minimally fixed them all errantly closing, I think the remaining problems related to decimal widths associated with % widths...

Comment: My solution does allow you to collapse all the columns, I am trying to think of a fix

Comment: Looks like you and I were working on nearly identical solutions and trying to solve a similar problem. I used a pseudo-element to help prevent premature collapse on the right side entry.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RfHSA/15/

Here's a working version of your script. You definitely need some javascript manipulation here to make it work. I tried to use as little as possible and as you can see from the results, it's a little shaky, but hopefully it gets you on the right track.

EDIT: Oh well, I tried, but the other guy's solution is better =P

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to prevent premature collapsing**

Tweaking your CSS gave this solution ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfHSA/27/)). It requires the `padding-top` to move from the `.listwrapper` to the `.featuredwrapper` to prevent premature collapse from top entry:

**Tweaked CSS**

```css
.outerbox {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
    margin-left:-4px;
    box-shadow:-5px 0px 5px rgba(51,51,51,0.85);
    -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-out;    
}

/*prevents premature collapse on right side entry*/
.outerbox:last-of-type:after { 
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -2px;
}

.listwrapper:hover .outerbox {
    width: 7%;
}

.listwrapper .outerbox:hover {
    width:72%;
}
```